# What to do if PACF is bad after 2 differences?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation

I am doing time series analysis. My goal is forecasting.

I am trying to fit a ARIMA model. However, after 2 differences, the PACF plots show bad results.

PACF after 2 differences

[image]

I even tried 6 differences:[image]

The original plot might be helpful

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the original plot, your time series does not contain a unit root. The series oscillates around a constant level of approx. 1000, which does not look like a random walk. Therefore, you should not difference at all.
You could probably try a logarithmic transformation as the positive spikes are higher than the negative ones, i.e. there is asymmetry.
Then try to identify the "right" AR and MA lags (if you fail to do that manually, you may always use the function `auto.arima` in the "forecast" package in R), and you will be good.